# How compound words "eighteen" and "roommate" are built

Tags: orthography, compounds

Why does eighteen not have two tees like roommate has two ems?

Comment: observation appreciated! and respected!

Comment: *Eighteen* is not a compound word, and spellings were not standardized until the 19th century or so— after both *eighteen* and *roommate* were in use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eighteen is not formed out of 'eight' and 'teen'; it's a number 'eighteen' in its own right. Etymologically, it once was a compound, though, of 'eight' and 'ten'. Old English *did* have both 't''s: ***[eahtatene](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=eighteen)***, but the two t's had merged by Middle English.

Roommate, on the other hand, is a [word from Modern English](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=roommate) and is indeed a compound word 'room' + 'mate'.

So the real answer to your question "**why are they different?**" is "**because eighteen is a much older word**".